# How can I do function partial application in Perl?

Tags: perl

Is there any way to achieve partial application in Perl?

Suppose, I want to do something like:

```
sub each_file($arr, $op) {
    $op->($_) for @{$arr};
    ...
} 

sub each_line($op, $file) {
    ... 
}

each_file($arr, each_line($op));
```

I want to partially apply `each_line()` to only `$op`, so it'll become a new function can be passed to `$each_file`, how do I express this in idiomatic Perl?

Comment: Are you talking about passing functions as arguments?  If so maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523566/in-perl-how-do-i-pass-a-function-as-argument-of-another-function) will answer your question.

Comment: @JohnC not just pass function, I want to pass curried function.

Comment: I was going to ask where the second param had gone . . . but you have answered that in the above comment. I think that is worth adding to the question. You can do this in Perl. Note that currying a function is more than just resolving the param, it usually involves pre-calculating the effects of that param and generating a *new* function, which you cannot do with a pre-existing function.

Comment: http://hop.perl.plover.com/Examples/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in Perl with two approaches combined:

- A function which returns a function reference
- Closures

Example:

```
sub each_file {
    my ($arr, $line_fn) = @_;
    $line_fn->($_) for @{$arr};
    ...
} 

sub each_line {
    my ($op, $file) = @_;
    ... 
}

sub make_line_processor {
  my ( $op ) = @_;

  # This is closed over $op, which effectively becomes 
  # a constant for the returned function
  my $fn = sub {
     return each_line( $op, @_ );
  };
  return $fn;
}


# To call it:
each_file( $arr, make_line_processor($op) );
```

This can be an even more useful technique in cases where you don't want `$op` directly, but some expensive-to-fetch derivation of it. In which case you would calculate the derived value just once (in the `make_line_processor` function) and close over that instead.

Comment: Not bad, I've seen this in Modern Perl, probably the furthest Perl can reach, I've just started using Perl, maybe my guess is not accurate.

Answer (score 1):

```
# given some $op as implied by your code snippet
each_file($arr, sub { each_line($op, shift) });
# shift op will be applied when anonymous sub { … } is called
```

(Your code snippet doesn't make it entirely clear what you intend `$op` to be when you make the call to `each_line`. It's usually better to present small working programs.)

Answer (score 0):

You can roll this functionality up into a class.  Then you can [overload the subroutine dereference operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/overload.html#*-_Dereferencing_) to make it look like your class is really a code reference.

```
package Partial;

use overload '&{}' => \&call;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $code = shift;
    bless {code => $code, args => \@_}, $class;
}

sub call {
    my ($self) = @_;
    return sub{ $self->{code}->(@{$self->{args}}, @_) }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
sub printArgs {
    print join ", ", @_;
    print "\n";
}

my $partial = Partial->new(\&printArgs, 'foo', 'bar');
$partial->('baz', 'bat');
# prints foo, bar, baz, bat
```